# SSIS package unable to write csv file to shared location

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

SSIS Job was able to run and create CSV files to shared location until last week when it was executed from scheduled job. The ssis package reports success but does not write file to shared location. When I run the package manually from visual studio it works fine. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Permissions to the file share seem to be your issue.

When running the package as a scheduled job from SQL Agent.  It is executed under the context of the service account for the SQL Agent Service.  So make sure the the sql agent account has the appropriate read/write access to the file share, and/or set the job to execute as a user with enough permissions.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13501630)

Comment: @IlVic it absolutely is an answer to the question!  the most likely cause of the OP issue is that he/she missed the fact that when executing a SQL agent job the context of the SQL Agent service account is used and therefore that account needs permission to the file share. This was clearly stated.  Are you sayign it is not an answer because I asked a follow up question in an Answer okay I have edited it so there is not a question mark.

Comment: You are right, I was misled by the final question mark. Your answer really does solve the question.

Comment: I have given full access permissions to the SQL Server Agent the job is running under but the behavior has not changed. Still reports success on the job but does not create CSV file at the share location

Comment: Can you post the details of your package so we can understand precedence.  Such as what task feeds into the dataflow that you are attempting to populate the CSV with?

Answer (score 0):

You need to give Modify permissions to the file share for the SQL Server Agent account. Executing an SSIS package in Visual Studio is executing it under the context of your account (or the account that you are logged onto the server with if doing it from a server). But when you use SQL jobs to execute the ssis package, then it runs under the context of the service account that SQL Server Agent is running under.

Comment: I have given full access permissions to the SQL Server Agent the job is running under but the behavior has not changed. Still reports success on the job but does not create CSV file at the share location

Comment: Are you setting permissions at the folder level or the share? Make sure it's the share permissions.

Comment: The permissions were applied at the share level.